# Accidentally created a repo within an existing repo and committed to the nested one, how can I transfer the commits of the inner one to the outer one?

Tags: git

So I've cloned a git repo, then somehow added a new repo within it, likely by spinning up a project with a framework I haven't worked with before, and I think it got automatically added in that process. Then I added a bunch of commits to the inner repo, and now I need to move them to the outer repo, and I'd like to remove the inner repo. Is it possible to do this safely?

Comment: Of course. Make a scratchpad repo, fetch the two histories, then create the history you thought you were making from the pieces. Exactly how to splice them together is going to depend on what they look like and where each oopsed-history commit's content fits in the broken extension to the existing history, Git's data structure is *bone* simple, this won't be hard, but there are quite a lot of details to splicing together a shattered bone, you're going to have to describe the pieces. Pick representative bad commits you made to both, detail their structure and what they should look like.

Comment: In the end I used subtree (see my accepted answer) and it was really quite simple (but it was a simple use case).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I used `git subtree` within the old repo:

```
git subtree add -P my_new_repo_copy ./my_new_repo/.git/ master
rm -r my_new_repo
mv my_new_repo_copy my_new_repo
git add my_new_repo
git commit
```

The last add/commit was just for the rename, all my previous commits were preserved by `subtree`. So it's not completely clean, but the history was there and that's what's important.

Answer (score 1):

I will call the real repo MAIN and the one you created SUB.
If you created SUB inside MAIN, then physically SUB's working directory should be inside the MAIN working directory. Let's call it SUB_FOLDER.

I see two solutions here. The first one is kind of a caveman solution: If you don't have so many altered files, create a new branch on MAIN, and make sure it's checkout. Go to SUB_FOLDER and check out your latest commit. Then physically move the altered files one level up to the MAIN working directory. You can add and commit the altered files to your new branch on MAIN and work your way through there.

The second solution is to turn the SUB repo into a BARE repo and use it as another remote with your MAIN repo.
(A bare repo is a Git repo without a working tree. You can't commit, merge.. etc in it. But you can clone it like any other remote and then push changes to it. It's the .git directory inside a regular Git Repo with the bare option turned true.)

For the second solution, while you are inside MAIN_FOLFER:

```
mv SUB_FOLDER/.git ../SUB.git
```

CD into SUB.git and run:

```
git config --bool core.bare true
```

CD back into your MAIN_FOLDER and run:

```
git remote add subbare ../SUB.git
git fetch subbare
```

Now you should be able to see your commits in the log.
You can try the merge subbare/master but you might get this error:

```
fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories
```

If you got the error just cherry-pick your desired commits:

```
git cherry-pick <commit-id>
```